# Android Studio, change EditText selected text pointer colors

Tags: android-layout

I've been making a chat for a project of mine but how to change the color of these pointers?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the `android:textCursorDrawable` attribute to @null should result in the use of `android:textColor` as the cursor color.

or you can use Style look like this

```
<style name="AppTheme.EditText" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.EditText">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">#8AFFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/edit_text_background</item> // background (bottom line at this case)
    <item name="android:textCursorDrawable">@color/white</item>  // Cursor
    <item name="android:textSelectHandle">@drawable/my_white_icon</item> // For pointer normal state and copy text state
    <item name="android:textSelectHandleLeft">@drawable/my_white_icon</item>
    <item name="android:textSelectHandleRight">@drawable/my_white_icon</item>
</style>
```

hope it help

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I managed to use this instead: <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorPrimary</item> 
inside styles.xml. This way I don't need to change the icon itself, thanks for your reply though, now I learned how to change the icons too if I ever need to! :)